# RewriteRules not stopping with [L] flag?

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite

A simpel mod rewrite in .htaccess. If  I open for example /lib/js/core/jquery.min.js, Apache2 takes the last rule and not the first. How can I fix this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^lib/js/core/(.+)$ core/lib/js/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Solve the problem, by recplace the first **L** flag the flag **END**

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRules ought to be processed in order. Are you sure it's actually matching the first regex? Try adding a leading slash i.e.

```
RewriteRule ^/lib/js/core/...$
```

Comment: I would like th first regex matching, but this is the problem. As slash at the end no not get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you use rewriterules in .htaccess file (which I and the apache people discourage strongly) you have to be aware that every rule that matches will result in a subrequest, and that thus all rules will be processed again. Since your second rule matches everything it wil be applied during this subrequest.

Not being able to stop these subrequest from happening was apparently a big enough nuisance that the END flag was introduced, but this requires Apache 2.4, which is not that widespread yet.